# DropdownButton flutter

Tags: flutter

Buenas tarde estoy intentando obtener el valor que genero en un DropdownButton este es mi codigo de el, obtengo el valor y cambia pero requiero el valor para poder ingresar el dato a firebase

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dropdwntext extends StatefulWidget {
  final String valorObtenido;

  Dropdwntext({
    this.valorObtenido,
    //@required this.valorObtenido,
  });

  @override
  _DropdwntextState createState() => _DropdwntextState();
}

class _DropdwntextState extends State<Dropdwntext> {
  String dropdownValor = 'Comida';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValor,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValor = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: <String>[
        'Comida',
        'otros'
      ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

en esta pagina lo llamo tengo dudas de como obtener el valor seleccionado, como puedo asignar el valor para recuperar,  al recuperar la información poder realizar el manejo?

```
 Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Dropdwntext(
                    
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que en vez de las imágenes coloque el código,así sera mas fácil que te ayuden a resolver tu problema.

Comment: muchas gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es obtener el valor de los **items** del `DropDownButton`, puedes hacerlo mediante atributos estáticos.
Creas una clase y defines un atributo estático,quien sera el que tenga el valor del **item** seleccionado en el `DropDownButton`

```
class Estatica{
  static String miValor="";
}
```

Luego guardas el valor de tu item selecionado en esta variable estatica:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValor,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      ...
      ...
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          
          dropdownValor = newValue;

          //aqui realizas el guardado del item seleccionado en la variable estatica
          Estatica.miValor=newValue;
          
        });
      },
```

Luego esta variable estática: `Estatica.miValor` puedes utilizarla en cualquier parte solo importando tu archivo donde la creaste para utilizarla.

Ahora si tu deseas, puedes crearte un botón en cualquier parte del código y visualizar esta variable en consola con un `print(Estatica.miValor)`, para que compruebes que contiene el item seleccionado en el **DropDownButton**

Comment: si me funciono de esa manera :O muchas gracias había intentado algo similar lo único es que no declare una variable dentro de la clase muchas gracias